# Getting URL of HTML 5 video

Tags: html, flash, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to the get the URL of this HTML 5 video but I can't seem to find it. I looked in Chrome dev tools but couldn't find anything. It's not even possible to right-click and view source on the video. I had to do it on another part of the website. You can switch between HTML5 and flash by selecting it by right clicking.

Here is the URL: http://aframe.com/.

I'm talkin about the video on the home page at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/38fnyo4peb`. (Page retrieved 15-May-2015, YMMV, etc.)

Their player is hijacking right clicks, but you can see what the URL is by looking at the `href` attribute on the `a` element enclosing the thumbnail that you click to start the video.